# SET ParseOnly with result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

From c# I am trying to check, if SQL is valid using `SET PARSEONLY ON`, as you see in the following example

```
BEGIN TRY
   SET PARSEONLY ON UPDATE SchedulerAction S ET
   SELECT 1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT -1
END CATCH
```

In SQL this gives the error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'S'.
```

But my problem is, that this error is not caught by `try-catch`, and somehow neither `SELECT`s are run.

If I change the SQL to `SET PARSEONLY ON UPDATE SchedulerAction SET`.
It gives the error below

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

But it neither gave a result from `SELECT`

If I changed it to a valid SQL like `SET PARSEONLY ON UPDATE SchedulerAction SET Action = 1` neither the `SELECT` in `try` is run.

Can I somehow get the result of, if the validation was correct or wrong by returning e.g. a `SELECT` or something similar?

Comment: Did you try running it in your `SSMS` ?

Comment: Yes, and as you see in my edited question, this is what it returned

Comment: `SET PARSEONLY` still checks syntax, and the syntax of this statement is invalid. You can wrap the whole thing in an `EXEC`, though (including the `PARSEONLY` if you don't want it to do anything if the statement is valid). If all you care about is syntactical validity from C#, however, another option is to use [`TSqlParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am only caring if it is valid, but it is not possible to use TSqlParser for me :( How can I wrap it inside EXEC, as I tried with `EXEC sp_sqlexec 'SET PARSEONLY ON UPDATE SchedulerAction SET Action=1'`

Comment: I didn't say anything about `sp_sqlexec`. :-P `EXEC ('SET PARSEONLY ON; UPDATE ...')` will produce a run-time error if the statement is invalid, which `TRY .. CATCH` will catch.

Comment: Thanks for your help @JeroenMostert. Will you please provide it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doable by not making the statement part of the original block, but executing it dynamically:

```
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'UPDATE SchedulerAction S ET';
BEGIN TRY
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SET PARSEONLY ON;' + @Statement;
   EXEC(@sql);
   SELECT 1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT -1
END CATCH
```

The semicolon between `SET PARSEONLY ON` and the other statement is not a luxury, as some statements will not parse correctly without statement terminators (like `SEND` statements, among others).

Mere syntactical validity may still mean the statement fails semantic constraints, and I don't mean obvious ones like misspelled table names: `SELECT * FROM sys.tables ORDER BY $` is invalid because constants are not allowed in an `ORDER BY` clause (and yes, `$` on its own is a constant), but it will still parse correctly. Using `SET NOEXEC ON` instead of `SET PARSEONLY ON` will catch these, but at the cost of not allowing some statements that may only occur in a batch on their own (like `CREATE VIEW`).

Comment: Shouldn't you execute `SET PARSEONLY OFF` after the `EXEC`?

Comment: There is no need -- any `SET` options are only in effect for the duration of the `EXEC` and do not affect the calling batch. (This is not documented, as far as I can tell, but it *is* how it works.)

Comment: (For `SET PARSEONLY`specifically it is even less relevant, because it only takes effect at compile time and not at runtime, so it *can't* affect the calling batch even if `SET` options were propagated.)

Answer (score 0):

TRY-CATCH catches run-time errors.   Syntax errors are caught at parsing time.   A syntax error in your TRY block will not cause the CATCH block to execute.

What you are seeing is expected behavior.